# Medium.com Invalid Json?

Tags: python, fetch, scrape

I am trying to fetch the latest posts from Medium.com so for example, I go here

https://medium.com/circle-blog/latest?format=json

But when I copy and paste that entire JSON into JSONEditorOnline.org, I get error saying

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
])}while(1);</x>{"su
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ']'
```

I realize error is because of the random stuff in the front

```
])}while(1);</x>
```

So how would I remove that using Python?

After I remove, I want to dump it into a JSON file

```
with open('medium.json', 'w') as json1:
    json1.write(json.dumps(JSONWITHWHILE(1)REMOVED))
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I wouldn't care about that since it's obviously broken JSON. But if you need, simply find the first opening curly-bracket and remove everything before...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with it since it's obviously not a valid JSON but if you need it, you can try to locate the first opening curly-bracket and simply remove everything before it:

```
valid_json = broken_json[broken_json.find('{'):]
```

**Explanation:**

- `broken_json.find('{')` returns the position (index) of the first occurrence of the character `{` in the string `broken_json`
- `broken_json[X:]` - is a string slice, it returns the substring of `broken_json` starting on the position `X`

An advantage over the LeKhan's solution is that when that JSON becomes valid, your code will be still working even with this fix in place. Also, his solution will return a broken JSON if it contains the substring `</x>` inside its fields (which may be valid).

**Note:** it's probably not a bug but it's there intentionally for some reason. There's for example the module Medium JSON feed which [handles it very similarly](https://github.com/frandiox/medium-json-feed/blob/e6f5654febf60b95d17701bc6d3a43be5ecf2864/index.js#L29) - it's also stripping everything before the first opening curly-bracket.

According to [this article](https://medium.com/statuscode/building-a-basic-web-service-to-display-your-medium-blog-posts-on-your-website-using-aws-api-48597b1771c5), it's there to prevent "*JSON hacking*", whatever it means.

Comment: Fair point, this surely is the better solution for most cases :) Only downside to both approaches is if we have something like this `]{)}while(1);</x>`. That would be even trickier, but its messy to parse anyhow.

Comment: @LeKhan9 Yep, but it looks like it's some static garbage Medium is intentionally adding to JSON outputs, this about one year old module is also [stripping it](https://github.com/frandiox/medium-json-feed/blob/e6f5654febf60b95d17701bc6d3a43be5ecf2864/index.js#L29) before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting that string by `</x>` and then get the second index:

```
clean_json = raw_json.split('</x>')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Medium didn't provide JSON objects But they are providing RSS feeds. Therefore you could convert the RSS feeds to JSON objects. Use the link below and replace your user name instead of userName.

```
https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/<userName>
```

for this question, you can use the below link

https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/circle-blog